# Notification not working in release mode React Native (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When App is open first time all the notification comes in foreground, background and App kill mode.
After App kill, No notification comes in any mode (foreground, background and App kill) in iOS React native

I used this library : [React-native-push-notification-ios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/push-notification-ios)

> I changed my Appdelegate.mm file.
> I update firebase version (18.3.0 to 15.7.0)

Here I shared my Appdelegate.mm file code

```
[ReactNativeExceptionHandler replaceNativeExceptionHandlerBlock:^(NSException *exception, NSString *readeableException){

    // THE CODE YOU WRITE HERE WILL REPLACE THE EXISTING NATIVE POPUP THAT COMES WITH THIS MODULE.
    //We create an alert box
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:@"Critical error occurred"
                                message: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",
                                          @"Apologies..The app will close now \nPlease restart the app\n",
                                          readeableException]
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    // We show the alert box using the rootViewController
    [rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

    // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
    // By default when an exception is raised we will show an alert box as per our code.
    // But since our buttons wont work because our click handlers wont work.
    // to close the app or to remove the UI lockup on exception.
    // we need to call this method
    // [ReactNativeExceptionHandler releaseExceptionHold]; // to release the lock and let the app crash.

    // Hence we set a timer of 4 secs and then call the method releaseExceptionHold to quit the app after
    // 4 secs of showing the popup
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0
                                     target:[ReactNativeExceptionHandler class]
                                   selector:@selector(releaseExceptionHold)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];

    // or  you can call
    // [ReactNativeExceptionHandler releaseExceptionHold]; when you are done to release the UI lock.
  }];


  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
   
  return YES;
}

// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  [[FIRAuth auth] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRAuthAPNSTokenTypeUnknown];
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
if ([[FIRAuth auth] canHandleNotification:userInfo]) {
   completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
   return;
}else{
[RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo
                                fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
}
//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:
             (void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))
                 completionHandler {
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge |
                    UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// delete the badge
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
// delete the notifications
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] removeAllDeliveredNotifications];
}
```

Here is my App.tsx code

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage: any) => {
      console.log(
        globalThis.isNotification,
        'globalThis.isNotification in app.tsx file',
      );
      console.log('remoteMessage>>>>>>>>.', remoteMessage);
   
      if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          if (globalThis.isNotification) {
            console.log(
              'globalThis.isNotification>>>>>.',
              globalThis.isNotification,
            );
          } else {
            PushNotificationIOS.addNotificationRequest({
              id: remoteMessage.messageId,
              body: remoteMessage.notification.body,
              title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
              userInfo: remoteMessage.data,
            });
          }
        }
        messaging()
        .getInitialNotification()
        .then(async remoteMessageIOS => {
          console.log('remote mesage at initial>>>>>>', remoteMessageIOS);

          if (remoteMessageIOS) {
            globalThis.isNotification = true;
          } else {
            globalThis.isNotification = false;
          }
        });
        if (globalThis.isNotification) {
          console.log('in if >>>>>>>>>>>>');
        } else {
          console.log('in else11 >>>>>>>>>>>>');
          messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
            console.log(remoteMessage, '>>>>>...remoteMessage');
            if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
              if (remoteMessage.notification) {
                PushNotificationIOS.addNotificationRequest({
                  id: remoteMessage.messageId,
                  body: remoteMessage.notification.body,
                  title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
                  userInfo: remoteMessage.data,
                });
              }
            }
          });
        }

      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

Please let me know where I go wrong, If anyone having any idea related to this,
All notification work in debug mode, but in release mode after app kill no notifications comes

Comment: This library is already having open issues with respect to your problem,
https://github.com/react-native-push-notification/ios/issues/312